# Differences in Kafka and Rabbit producers-broker acknowledgement

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka

From my understanding RabbitMQ producers require acknowledgment when sending messages to the broker which provides a delivery-guarantee. Kafka producers ***does not*** require acknowledgement from the broker. Does that mean there’s no delivery-guarantee with Kafka? If not, how does Kafka provide delivery guarantee without acknowledgement?

Is my understanding correct? Please correct any misunderstandings that I have as I’m still learning about these systems.

Comment: Note: RabbitMQ producer does not require too acknowledgement. You can enable ack using transaction or using the publish/confirm

Comment: @NicolasLabrot Can you elaborate on "enable ack using transaction?". How is that different than regular acknowledgement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka is actually flexible about this.

The number of acknowledgements for producers is configurable. The configuration is called `RequiredAcks`. In fact, required acks is set on `ProduceRequest` level, but I've never seen implementations where a single producer instance allows producing messages with different required acks settings.

`RequiredAcks` is an integer value which means "how many acknowledgements the broker should wait before responding to a produce request".

Having `RequiredAcks` set to `0` (VERY not recommended for production) means "fire and forget", e.g. broker will respond immediately without waiting until data is written to log. This is the case where you could lose messages without even knowing about that.

Having `RequiredAcks` set to `1` means "wait until data is written to local log", where local log is log of the broker that received the request. Once your data is written to local log, broker responds.

Having `RequiredAcks` set to `-1` means "wait until the data is written to local log AND replicated by all ISRs".

Each `ProduceRequest` also has a `Timeout` field, which means "maximum time to wait for necessary amount of acknowledgements".

So Kafka supports acknowledging requests but allows turning acknowledgements off.

Answer (score 0):

In 0.9.0.0 and above, the producer#send has a return value Future you can get the offset of the message in the broker's partition. Meantime, you can implement Callback, if there is no exception, it's mean that the message has been sent to the correct broker.